# Using Plunker, How to access variable from the browser console

Tags: javascript, plunker

I'm using Plunker (http://plnkr.co/) to test JavaScript.  From the browser console I want to access variables that I defined in the script.

In Plunker, can anyone tell me how to access the variable "someValue" from the browser console.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var someValue = 3
      console.log(someValue);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I figured out one possible solution.  In Google Chrome's Developer Tools on the bottom of the developer console "top frame" can be changed to "run.plnkr.co" (see image below).  This will change the scope of the console and the variables in the script can now be accessed.

[image: Plunker in Google Chrome]

Here's the answer for jsFiddle: 
[Access variables in jsFiddle from Javascript console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328963/access-variables-in-jsfiddle-from-javascript-console)

Comment: Problem with this is that when the preview refreshes you could pushed back to "top frame". So anything logged to the console on load is missed.

Answer (score 1):

or you can use http://jsbin.com/ which displays the console directly

Answer (score 1):

using a separate window helped me debug the scopes and everything.

just follow as below, and then use **F12**

[image: expand to a seperate window]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `console.debug( variable )`;

Take a look in this post as well:

[Difference between console.log() and console.debug()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876461/difference-between-console-log-and-console-debug)