# Difference between console.log() and console.debug()?

Tags: javascript, console, console.log, web-developer-toolbar

Google  has not been helpful for me, since searching for "console.debug" just brings up a bunch of pages that have the words "console" and "debug" on them.

I'm wondering what the difference is between `console.log()` and `console.debug()`. Is there some way to use a bunch of `console.debug()` statements and then just flip a switch to easily shut off all debug statements from being sent to the console (like after launching a site)?

Comment: Here is how to disable the console.log outputs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215392/how-to-quickly-and-conveniently-disable-all-console-log-statements-in-my-code

Comment: You can put colors.
console.log('%c Sample Text', 'color:green;');

Or add some VAR in the text using:
console.log(\`Sample ${variable}\`, 'color:green;');

Answer (score 83, accepted):

For at least IE, Firefox and Chrome consoles, .debug() is just an alias for .log() added for improved compatibility

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api#consoledebugobject_object

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772183(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: In Chrome `debug()` comes up in blue and `log()` in black

Comment: A serious improvement over log().

Comment: From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console:
**console.debug()** - _Note: Starting with Chromium 58 this method only appears in Chromium browser consoles when level "Verbose" is selected._

Comment: Using Debug in Chrome: Calling Debug are not Allowed

Comment: Not only alias. In Chrome, the Log level for `debug()` is Verbose, but for `log()` it is Info.

Answer (score 171):

Technically `console.log` `console.debug` and `console.info` are identical
However the way they display the data is little different. `console.debug` is not visible by default in the browser's JS console. It can be enabled by using the console's filter options.

`console.log` Black color text with no icon

`console.info` Blue color text with icon

`console.debug` Pure black color text

`console.warn` Yellow color text with icon

`console.error` Red Color text with icon

```js
var playerOne = 120;
var playerTwo = 130;
var playerThree = 140;
var playerFour = 150;
var playerFive = 160;

console.log("Console.log" + " " +  playerOne);
console.debug("Console.debug" + " " +playerTwo);
console.warn("Console.warn" + " " + playerThree);
console.info("Console.info" + " " + playerFour);
console.error("Console.error" + " " + playerFive);
```

[image]

Comment: In google chrome browser `info` level logs are simply shown with an icon (same as in the snapshot) but the text (`console.info` text in your post) is in black color and background color of the row is white. Possibly your snapshot for firefox browser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very clear with the screenshot. Gotta ask though, why the string concatenation? Why not just `console.log("Console.log");` instead of `console.log("Console.log" + " " +  playerOne);`? What does the `" " +  playerOne` do?

Comment: In my console, I get the same display with `console.log("Console.log");
console.debug("Console.debug");
console.warn("Console.warn"); 
console.info("Console.info"); 
console.error("Console.error");`

Comment: It's also a good idea to note that, console.error and console.warn output to stderr, while the others output to stdout

Answer (score 54):

They are almost identical - the only difference is that debug messages are hidden by default in recent versions of Chrome (you have to set the log level to `Verbose` in the Devtools topbar while in console to see debug messages; log messages are visible by default).

Comment: Hi, this seems true, but I am unable to find any information on this behavior. The [Chrome docs](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consolelogobject-object) do not mention it as of today.

Comment: Now I finally understood "set log level to Verbose on top of console". You mean in Dev Tools there is the console at the bottom. At the top of this section, along with Filter and the frame selector, there is also a verbosity drop down for the logs (preset to "Info")

Comment: This is the most relevant answer. Everyone mentions colors but this is IMO more important.

Answer (score 17):

`console.info` ,`console.debug` methods are identical to `console.log`.

- `console.log` [Printing statement](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consolelogobject-object)
- `console.info` Black color text with "i" icon in blue color
- `console.debug` Blue Color text

Documentation:

- [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consolelogobject-object)
- [IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772183(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/console/console-api#logging-custom-messages)
- [FireFox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/console)
- [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Console/Console.html)

Comment: Console.info prints blue color, console.warn prints yellow color and console.error  prints red color

Comment: I have tested in the Chrome 52.0.2743.82
Console.Info prints in black color with blue icon,
Console.warn prints in black color with yellow icon 
console.error prints in Red color  with red icon

Comment: please edit your answer accordingly so that I can upvote or remove downvote, did you notice the blue colored "i" icon before the printed text while using console.info()

Answer (score 11):

If you want the ability to disable logging after a product is finished you could override the `console.debug()` function or make another custom one.

```
console.debug = function() {
    if(!console.debugging) return;
    console.log.apply(this, arguments);
};

console.debugging = true;
console.debug('Foo', {age:41, name:'Jhon Doe'});
```

> Foo▸ {age: 41, name: "Jhon Doe"}

```
console.debugging = false;
console.debug('Foo', {age:26, name:'Jane Doe'});
```

> No output

However I havent figured a way to color the outputs as well.

Comment: works well with using ANSI escape codes for coloring: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41407246/1175053

Answer (score 7):

I know it's old, but to continue on @Espen's answer, you can separate responsibilities and use console.log for your regular logs that should also appear on production, and for console.debug you can do something like that:

```
if (env === 'production') {
   console.debug = function () {};
}
```

This will override console.debug and it won't print anything.
This way you don't have to worry about things that *should* appear in prod environment.

Comment: for further info, in React a good approach is shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56276325/how-can-remove-console-log-in-the-production-build-of-a-react-application-create

Answer (score 2):

From Documentation of browsers,The `log`,`debug`and also `info` methods are identical in implementation wise but varies in  color and icon

https://jsfiddle.net/yp4z76gg/1/

Comment: This should be a comment or add more explanation with answer for how both are identical or no difference to understand OP and others.Thanks