# console.log vs console.debug - perfomance

Tags: javascript, performance, benchmarking

Does replacing `console.log` with `console.debug` in a quite heavy javascript application affect in any way the overall perfomance?

Thanks

---

Eg.

```
const startTime = new Date().getTime();
for (var id = 0; id < 100000000; id++) {
  console.log('test') // vs console.debug('test')
}
console.log(new Date().getTime()-startTime);
```

---

In Chrome nowadays `console.debug` logs only appears when level "Verbose" is selected so I assumed it would be slightly faster but it's actually slighty slower according to my benchmark results therefore I would appreciate some insights.

Thanks

---

**UPDATE** - Some heuristic results:

Using `console.debug` instead of `console.log` in long running processes, I noticed a slight (~5/10%) improvement in memory usage both in Chrome and Opera (latest version).

Comment: Well, you have some sample code there - why not just try running those two alternations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between console.log() and console.debug()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876461/difference-between-console-log-and-console-debug)

Comment: you need performance in production code. thus the highest performance is to remove it when you push the code. learn to use breakpoints.

Comment: @CertainPerformance According to my results console.debug is slower and that surprises me so I am asking for feedback. Thanks

Comment: @DragonKnight Agree, logs are already removed in production. I would like to improve perfomance on a local environment.

Comment: @AramGrigoryan this question is specific about perfomance and benchmarks, thanks. Also, that's an old question - in chrome now for example console.debug is not printed out by default  (logs only appears when level "Verbose" is selected)  so I assumed it would be slightly faster but it's actually slighty slower according to my results.

Comment: I would think that if it does, it is negligible. I will say one of the benefits of using `console.debug` is you can fine-tune its use and turn it off and on.

Comment: while working in dev env using console.log vs console.debug will never make a difference. there are other things that affect performance much much much worse e.g. source maps