# Why doesn't JSFiddle output results for this code

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I have been using the Firebug javascript console to test short scripts. Several people have suggested using JSFiddle instead. The problem is I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I enter my code in the js panel and hit run but nothing happens. I am assuming something should output to results? I tried different settings, reading the JSFiddle documentation, reading other questions posted on Stackoverflow, but I can't figure it out. It seems like it should be so simple. Maybe it only works if I call it from HTML? http://jsfiddle.net/nngrey/QgxCn/ (I had to include my code to reference the link to JSFiddle.)

```
function Palindrome(str) {
    str = str.split("");
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] === " ") {
            str.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    revStr = str.reverse().join("");
    str = str.join("");
    if (revStr === str) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return str;
}

str = "dont nod";
Palindrome(str);
```

Comment: alert(Palindrome(str)); or console.log(Palindrome(str));

Comment: You have to do *something* with the return value. Otherwise it's just lost. The "Results" panel only shows the HTML you put in the HTML panel.

Comment: Thank you. Alert works, but console.log doesn't seem to.

Comment: @Nathan `console.log` will output a message to the Web Console. To see it you should open your control panel first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without any html to display your answer you can alert it to see the results.

```
function Palindrome(str) {
  str = str.split("");
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === " ") {
        str.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
revStr = str.reverse().join("");
str = str.join("");
if (revStr === str) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
    return str;
}

str = "dont nod";
alert(Palindrome(str));
```

Comment: Also your `return str;` will never get returned because of the `return false;` and `return true;` before it.  The function stops running once its returned ie It only returns once result.

Comment: Thanks! Do you understand the difference between the Firebug's Javascript console, Chrome's Javascript console, and JSFiddle's interface? That is, when I type into the righthand side of Firebug's console, I get all kinds of feedback. Not so much with Chrome and JSFiddle. I feel like I am not using these two correctly. There must be more that I am missing.

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328963/access-variables-in-jsfiddle-from-javascript-console if I open up your fiddle and then in the `Chrome` java script console I change `<top frame>` to `result(fiddle.jshell.net/)` and on the top left if you change `onLoad` to `No Wrap - in <body>` you can then re run the fiddle and  you can access the functions and variables in the console `console.log(Palindrome(str));` works.  This seems to be unique to JSFiddle though I have never had trouble accessing variables from the console on local development.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this jsFiddle to output stuff with console.log. Same idea as alert(), but without a popup you have to close. Thanks to [Wayne Koort](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://www.wkoorts.com/wkblog/2013/01/26/console-log-with-jsfiddle/&ei=kxYfU7mqBMq1kAesmIDQBA&usg=AFQjCNGkrgCs7xMrg8Ve_89rTq3VKawlfQ&sig2=rRMXHZsJCpDcUkzzrECbWw&bvm=bv.62788935,d.eW0).

http://jsfiddle.net/TEHLb/

```
var consoleLine = "<p class=\"console-line\"></p>";
console = {
    log: function (text) {
        $("#console-log").append($(consoleLine).html(text));
    }
};
var myVar = "foo";
console.log('Your variable has the value ' + myVar);
```

Comment: Thanks, started using this (= forked it).

Answer (score 1):

you need `alert(Palindrome(str));`

try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QgxCn/2/)